# How to preselect ion-option

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm new in Ionic and i try to use the ion-select dynamically with preselect option.

I just want edit my profile with some value. In this example i can set multiple language that the user can speak.

First i get all languages set in my database with my API and i set my result in var LanguagesData.
[My result in console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpWJb.png)

Second i get currently languages spoken by my user and set the result in currentLanguages
[My result in console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7exj.png)

Third my code :

```html
<ion-select name="languages" [(ngModel)]="currentLanguage" multiple="true">
     <ion-option *ngFor="let language of languagesData" [value]="language">{{language.language}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

My values are not preselect.
If i replace `[(ngModel)]="currentLanguage"` by `[(ngModel)]="LanguagesData"` all values are preselect.

Can you explain me what i did wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problem with a tricks (i'm not proud of it).
Currently i get my 2 arrays of data from api call.
If i use the base array it does not work.
But if i do someting like that :

```html
let i = 0;
                let j = 0;

                while (i < this.currentLanguage.length) {
                  while (j < this.languagesData.length) {

                    if (this.currentLanguage[i].id == this.languagesData[j].id)
                      this.finalLanguage.push(this.languagesData[j]);
                    j += 1;
                  }
                  j = 0;
                  i += 1;
                }
```

It works when i use finalLanguage instead of currentLanguage.
I don't really understand why ...

Comment: This saved my ass big time. I had tried everything else and was just about to write my own select box with checkboxes. Creating the array from "scratch" kinda like you, it works. Magic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-select name="languages" [(ngModel)]="currentLanguage" multiple="true">
     <ion-option *ngFor="let language of languagesData" [value]="language.language">{{language.language}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

You were missing `[value]="language.language"`

Hope it solves your proble.

Comment: Hey' !
It's not working. Furthermore i need to pass the object because i need several info of the object and not the name (or id for example)

Comment: what is your `currentLanguage` value?

Comment: `currentLanguage` should match language to get it as default, so look if both objects are same, e.g. `currentLanguage={"language":"english"}`

Comment: atm my value are :  `0
:
{id: "15ef682f-a6de-4907-b48e-d777d5b247b5", language: "Portuguese", createdAt: "2018-03-14 15:38:47", updatedAt: "2018-03-14 15:38:47"}
1
:
 {id: "0469999c-c395-4df5-8334-9362fc869839", language: "Italian", createdAt: "2018-03-14 15:38:53", updatedAt: "2018-03-14 15:38:53"} `